# Poem or short story: silver cocklebur(r)?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, fairy-tales, folklore, poetry

Does anyone know of a short story, or possibly a poem, that involves a silver cockleburr?
The story has a fairy tale vibe. I think the protagonist is a young woman. There's somewhere she's not supposed to go, possibly to see a witch (could be fairies, but I don't think so). She goes to the forbidden place anyway and thinks no one will find out, but when she returns everyone can tell that she went there because there's a silver cockleburr stuck to the hem of her cloak or her dress (maybe her hair). I don't think we learn what happens to her--the last line is just sort of an ominous "and on her hem/cloak/dress was the silver cockleburr."

I think I read it as a kid or early in high school, so it would have been published at least 10-20 years ago. My family owned a lot of old books that I read while growing up (though my parents have no idea what I'm talking about), so it could be an older story. I have searched several fairy tale/folklore databases with no luck, so it is probably not common/part of a canon.  I also started reading adult fairy tale compilations fairly young, so it very well could have been in one of those. Not knowing is driving me nuts!

Comment: Could this be what you're after; http://www.gaiaonline.com/forum/test-forum/setsuna-s-samples/t.75993389/ - it seems to be some sort of fanfic site. Search for burr and you'll see a story that seems to match your description...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found this thread when I Googled "Silver Cockleburr" because, in the spirit of Halloween, I'm looking up all the old stories that creeped me out to no end as a kid in the early-mid 90s. I remember the Silver Cockleburr was a short story written by a teenage girl either in American Girl magazine in the 1990s, or in the children's literary magazine Stone Soup from the same time period. I subscribed to both of them and remember one of them having a scary story contest where they chose the best-written and scariest stories sent in by readers. The Silver Cocklebur was one of them. I remember that it was definitely in a magazine because the following month they had to run an apology for scaring so many of their readers! I loved it though.

I remember the last line too: "And on her right shift's shoulder, her little bony shoulder, and on her right shift's shoulder was a silver cocklebur." Very creepy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: By the way, CameraLucida, please let me know if you subscribed to either of those magazines in the 90s-- I've done some Googling and think I've broken the internet, since no evidence of this story pops up anywhere and I'd love to figure out where I read it as a kid! I remember there being some other great ones in that issue. If it's Stone Soup, I bet I could track it down as they're such a small magazine.

Comment: Upvoted as a semi-answer.

Comment: Oh man, that is totally it! I am fairly certain it was American Girl magazine--it definitely fits for what age I would have been when I read it and explains why it wouldn't have been something my parents were familiar with. It had creepy illustrations too, right? I'm recalling sort of fuzzy outlines with muted tones. I still can't remember much of the plot, but you totally nailed the last line. I am so pleased someone else remembered it!

Comment: it was an American girl magazine, because I wrote in to them when I was 10-ish because I was angry at them for publishing such a scary story and then published my letter and apologized....ha!

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this might be from a collection of [Ozark folk tales](https://www.google.com/search?q=silver%20AND%20cockleburr%20AND%20hem%20AND%20dress&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (two of the three only hits in books.google.com for "silver AND cockleburr AND dress AND hem", the third references a wird (not cockleburr) caught in the hem)?